# Normal RAM usage of the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Server Version)?

Tags: server, ram, memory-usage

my question is how much RAM a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server normaly uses? when nothing is installed on it?

Answer (score 3):

> my question is how much RAM a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server normaly uses?

Linux/Ubuntu is set up such that it will try to find the most optimal situation where data is kept in memory and it will take the least performance hit to drop it to disk (of course it is a bit more complex: you can change this behaviour to be less or more aggressive).

So stating a hard number is probably not possible.

```
watch -n 5 free -m
```

will show you the actual numbers though.

---

Looking at it from the recommendations for the server editions:

```
300 MHz x86 processor
192 MiB of system memory (RAM)
1 GB of disk space
Graphics card and monitor capable of 640x480
CD drive
```

You *need* at least 192 MiB to have a server that performs normally. So that could be an answer: 192 MiB will roughly be used from a vanilla install will a little overhead (otherwise I would expect the recommended number to be higher or lower). Anything more is nice but not needed.

Answer (score 0):

This will vary, depending how much RAM is installed -- up to a point, Ubuntu will use some fraction of the available RAM for system operation, and keep the remainder for applications.  If there's not enough installed RAM, Ubuntu will perform slowly due to excessive paging to swap, and if there's more than around 6 GB available, the RAM usage at idle won't increase further.  This is also affected by various settings that control swap usage -- how large the swap partition is, and "swappiness", which is a system setting you wouldn't normally adjust, that decides how aggressively the system will trade off free RAM for swap time.

My Kubuntu 14.04.2 LTS system (KDE Plasma workspace) uses around 70-75% of my installed 4 GB at idle after a fresh startup, but I do have some widgets that run immediately on startup; it might or might not use less without those widgets, as disabling them might simply reduce the amount of swap space used in the idle state.  If you have a lighter GUI (or run at command line) and no auto-start applications, you might use significantly less; if you have no swap partition and run a similarly weighty GUI, you might use more.

Comment: He has no GUI ;-)